# App not appearing in Google play store unless i remove the space between the name

Tags: android, namespaces, publish, displaytag

I made an android app and published it about two days ago. When I search for the game in Google play store, the game doesn't appear unless I remove the space between the name of the app. for example.. if I write 'racing horse' the app doesn't appear but if I write 'racinghorse' the app appears. Why is that? also the its says app "in prod" for the status of the app in Google developer console.

Has the app been published? How do I fix the spacing issue?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google's publication process. Talk to them

Answer (score 0):

**"in prod"**
means that your application is in the process of being published on the app store and will get published in a few hours. Everytime you update your app the same will appear.

However,
**the space** between the name issue is something unheard of and please contact Google for the same.

Comment: Ok, so maybe the name issue is happening because it has not been published yet...

Answer (score 0):

I think name space is not the issue from that side. Check your app name in `strings.xml` in `values` folder. If it is **racinghorse** then change it according to your requirement.

Comment: I checked and it says "racing horse" with a space

Comment: Post your strings.xml

Comment: <string name="signing_in">Signing in with Google</string>
    <string name="signing_out">Signing out</string>
    <string name="app_name">Racing Horse</string>

Answer (score 0):

I'm experiencing the same problem.  I contacted Google and they told me to search using quotations, e.g. "racing horse".

Like you, my strings.xml is correct.  Using the Amazon App Store the app can be found as normal as two words without the need for quotations.  Perhaps try Amazon too; see how your app displays there.

M.